# Code::Blocks Debugger : how to `step into` functions on line-by-line execution?

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks

When debugging a C++ program on `Code::Blocks 20.03`, I press `SHIFT+F7` to `step into` the program, then I begin pressing `F7` to go to the `next line` and `watch` variables changing in "real time".

But Code::Blocks 20.03's debugger won't enter any functions beside `main`, making it pretty useless, or forcing me to not use any function besides `main` (a bad programming practice).

How can I make Code::Blocks 20.03's debugger enter the functions too?

Comment: So, did you try shift+f7 when paused on a function call?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I use SHIFT+F7 at the first line of the program. Using it on a line of `main` that calls another function just makes the debugger go to the next line of `main` without entering the called function, just returning its result. Exactly as happened when using SHIFT+F7 on the first line of the program.

Comment: I would try a different IDE then, e.g. VSC. CB is poorly maintained (or was, last time I checked).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'll grant you the acceppted answer of this question if you provide an answer with instructions on how to accomplish what I want on any other free IDE that run on Windows 7.

Comment: Update to Win 10/11 or install Linux.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have Linux installed, but the dual boot isn't working properly, so I'm unable to boot into Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/709996/grub-debian-11-dual-boot-with-windows-7-uefi-gpt-ssd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set a `breakpoint` (red circle) exactly on the line the function `main` is defined;
2. Instead of pressing `F8` (the same as clicking `Debug->Start/Continue`), which would make the program just run until the last line and exit (only flashing on the screen before disappearing), press `Shift+F7` (the same as clicking `Debug->Step Into`), in order to make the debugger enter the function and not just run it completely and return its result;
3. Press `F7` (the same as clicking `Debug->Next line`) to keep watching the program run "step-by-step";
4. When any other function is called, and the debugger is on that line (yellow arrow), you may enter that other function too, by repeating step 2.

Reference: [ImageCraft - CodeBlocks Debugger Functions](https://imagecraft.com/help/ICCV8AVR/iccavr/1.5_-jdb/codeblocks_debugger_functions.htm).

> Source Line Stepping
>
> Once paused, you can continue execution:
>
> - Debug->Start/Continue **runs the program until the next breakpoint**.
> - Debug->next line runs the program until the next source line. **If the current source line contains a function call, it will “step over” the function call.**
> - Debug->Step into **will “step into” a function call, and pause at the next source line.**
> - Debug->Step out will continue program execution until the function call returns to its caller.
> - Debug->Next instruction and Debug->Step into instruction are assembly debugging commands, and should not be used within the CodeBlocks IDE. Instead, the corresponding commands in the ADT should be used.